# How to prove that the limit $\lim_{a \to 0+} \int_a^b -(\log x)^{-1} \, dx$ exists

Tags: calculus

Let $\delta$ be an element of $(0,1)$.  I need to find an upper bound for the integral from $0$ to delta of $-1/\log$.  Clearly, this is an improper integral, so I let a be an element of $(0,\delta)$ and try to then find the limit as a goes to $0$ from the right of this integral.  $-1/\log$ has no elementary primitive, so I need to use a different method.  So far I have shown that the function $-1/\log$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ and hence that the integral from a to delta of $-1/\log$ is less than or equal to $-(\delta - a) / \log(\delta)$.  Thus, as long as I knew that the limit as a goes to $0$ from the right of the integral from a to delta of $-1/\log$ EXISTS, it would follow that this limit would have to be less than or equal to $-(\delta - a) / \log(\delta)$ - I would have found an upper bound for the integral from 0 to delta of $-1/\log$.  But I don't know how to show that this limit exists.  Help please?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! please note that you can format equations using LaTeX for prettier (and more readable) questions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f:[0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(t)=-(\log t)^{-1}$ for $0<t<1$. Then $f$ is obviously continuous, and so for every $b<1$ the function 
$$
F:[0,b] \to \mathbb{R}, F(x)=\int_x^bf(t)dt
$$ 
is well defined. Furthermore, $F$ is differentiable, and in particular $F$ is continuous. Thus 
$$
F(0)=\lim_{a\to 0}F(a)=\lim_{a\to 0}\int_a^b-(\log(t))^{-1}dt.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral:
$$\int{\frac{-1}{\log{x}}}dx = -Li(x) + C$$
Where $Li(x)$ is the [Logarithmic Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html).

To prove that the integral exists on the region $[0,\delta]$ where $\delta < 1$, all you have to do is show that the function is continuous and bounded in that range (which it is). Since:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} -1/\log(x) = 0$$